# Updating Eye Transform Position in Swift for iOS 12.0+

Tags: swift, arkit, renderer, ios12, scnnode

I would like to continually output the updated eye transform matrices for an `ARFaceGeometry` in an `ARSession`. I have written the following so far and instead of updating the position continually, it simply outputs the initial position and continues to repeat those values. I have tried implementing an `updateFeatures(for node: SCNNode,using anchor: ARFaceAnchor)` for eye position and was not able to yield a different result. Would you have any tips/ glaring mistakes I failed to notice that could be causing the eyeTransform to not update?

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    var leftEyeTransform: simd_float4x4 { get {
        return currentFaceAnchor!.leftEyeTransform}
        }
    print("Left Eye: \(currentFaceAnchor!.leftEyeTransform)")
    guard anchor == currentFaceAnchor,
        let contentNode = selectedContentController.contentNode,
        contentNode.parent == node
        else { return }
    selectedContentController.renderer(renderer, didUpdate: contentNode, for: anchor)    
}
```

In the above, `currentFaceAnchor` is a `let` constant defined as an `ARFaceAnchor` in the `renderer(didAdd:)` method and `contentNode` is a `let` constant defined as `contentController.renderer(nodeFor: faceAnchor)`.

Comment: Koszonom szepen Dávid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not using the `anchor` that the renderer function gives you as a parameter. That `anchor` contains all of the updated information about the face/eye. The `currentFaceAnchor` that you're referring to only contains the information about the face anchor from when you first initialized it. If you were to add what's below you should see updating values from the `leftEyeTransform`.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard #available(iOS 12.0, *), let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor else { return }

    print("\(faceAnchor.leftEyeTransform)")
}
```

Comment: Went over the entire code and came to the same conclusion. Thank you :)